# How to disable mysql function in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project like `codepad.org` that inputs a php code and compile it and give `error or output`

I want to disable some functions like `mysql_query` and if anybody uses it then want to show some warning like `mysql_query() is disabled for some security reasons`

How can I disable the functions ?

Comment: I think you can do it in `php.ini`

Comment: on shared server i dont have access of php.ini but I can do with .htaccess but I am not getting how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `php.ini`

set `safe_mode` on/yes

then:

```
disable_functions = mysql_connect,system,exec,fopen,fputs,file_put_contents,mysql_query
```

on shared server you probably won't be able to do this without insecuring your own virtual root. .htaccess is limited according to server owner settings

in `.htaccess` you can change php flags like this:

```
php_flag disable_functions = mysql_connect,system,exec,fopen,fputs,file_put_contents,mysql_query
```

(maybe without the "=")

it still depends on the server config tho

Comment: using .htaccess can I do this ?

Comment: Thanks Dan, that worked but still I have a doubt that can I show some error message too if this function is disabled ??

Comment: you can do this by checking the uploaded scripts for string appearings of "mysql_", so if it contains words like "mysql_" you would print an error.

Comment: be very careful with your project as nifty people will try everything to circumvent your security. and please don't use `eval`. use output buffers (`ob_`), use strong `preg_match`es and validation

Comment: Thanks dan for such a good information, I had used somewhere eval but now I will try another alternet for that

Answer (score 1):

On shared hosting you still sometime have the opportunity to compile your own PHP and install it in your home directory. By doing so, you could disable some libraries at compile time. And have access to your *own* php.ini corresponding to your *own* installation of PHP.

Most of the time on shared hosting, this will imply to run your PHP scripts as CGI. With big performances penalties.

BTW, you mentioned a concern about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is "abusing" your code to perform unwanted *queries*. This is *not* calling an unexpected SQL *function*. That latter is [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) and could be possible, for example, if you blindly execute code from untrusted sources (using `eval()` just for mentioning that one). If you have such security holes -- you should rework you application instead of only relying on "clever configuration" or "patches" to prevent abuses.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is to remove the extensions in `php.ini`:

Change:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

To:

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

**Update:**

Probably you can block the IP address of your MySQL server using `.htaccess`, so users will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: on shared server I dont have access to php.ini

Comment: Why would you then disable the functions if you are not admin of the server? :D

Comment: as my project some one may inject some mysql query so i have to disable for my db security

Comment: How can they inject `mysql_query`? Are you using `EVAL()` on input?

Comment: Yep I have done that but still making some research about that if I can do that stuff

Comment: with this solution he won't be able to use the mysql libs for himself

Comment: Just saying, but you can create different groups of users on MySQL server. Restricting their rights to some harmless to your database queries as `SELECT`

Comment: @Jari you didnt understand what he's asking, did you?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Well, probably I understand. But I see nothing specific, so cannot help much.