# Block mysql functions in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, sql-injection

Is it possible to block some specific mysql functions like `sleep()`, `load_file()`, `extractvalue()` ...

Technology stack we are using:

- Spring Boot (Java)
- Hibernate
- Apache Tomcat

In php we can block mysql functions
[How to disable mysql function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314456/how-to-disable-mysql-function-in-php)
How can I do same for above technology stack ?

Comment: If you really wanted to conditionally expose these functions via REST API - **don't**. I mean at all. Otherwise, look for Spring Security tutorials, there are some comprehensive ones.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I don't want to expose these functions at all.

Comment: @Danish, you simply do not `grant execute` permission for them to any of your users. Databases have their own sets of permissions. Or like the other person said, do not use these in your code and do not expose them to outside.

Comment: Let suppose my web app is vulnerable to some sql injection. If i disable some functions that attackers commonly used in sql injection attack it will be frustrating for attacker to exploit target web app.

Comment: @Danish If you use always prepared statements SQL injections should not the problem. Don't build your SQL by yourself.

Comment: I was just finding a solution if in case there is some sql injection vulnerability left behind by mistake which is common.

Comment: The linked PHP question concerns PHP functions that perform MySQL tasks. Java doesn't implement those operations in the same way. For example the PHP function `mysql_connect()` would be equivalent to `DriverManager.getConnection()` in Java. It doesn't make any sense to try to "forbid" it. Java is not PHP, so don't try to apply PHP practices to Java. I suspect the problem here is the lack of experience with Java and understanding Java idioms in database access.

Comment: @Kayaman I was hoping for some config file that can be used to disable some specific mysql functions like for php there is php.ini

Comment: @Danish If you don't need these commands at all, you should follow  M. Prokhorov and remove the grants. But be aware that some commands are used by Java as   Kayaman  wrote. If you need these commands in your program, but protect against SQL injection, use prepared statements. There is no *left behind*.

Comment: @Danish use spring security it will handle sql injection as well as cors attacks

Comment: @SumeshTG Spring Security doesn't handle SQL injection. Could you give a reference?

Comment: Why do you think you need to block anything? What is your program supposed to do anyway?